# Is there a standard way to turn a Kotlin sequence into a java.util.Enumeration?

Tags: java, kotlin

They seem conceptually very similar. I wrote this function to solve the problem. But does anything exist in the standard library or elsewhere?

```
fun <T> Sequence<T>.toEnumeration(): Enumeration<T> {
    val iterator = this.iterator()
    return object : Enumeration<T> {
        override fun hasMoreElements() = iterator.hasNext()
        override fun nextElement(): T = iterator.next()
    }
}
```

Comment: Given that Enumeration was supposed to die with Java 1.2, I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: I was trying to use `SequenceInputStream`, which requires an `Enumeration`.

Comment: Yes, there's always an edge case where you'll need it, but they are too rare to justify standard library support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not available in the Standard Library.

However, `Sequence` has the [`iterator()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/-sequence/iterator.html) and [`asIterable()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/as-iterable.html) methods.

An `Iterator` is functionally equivalent to an `Enumeration` and the preferred way of iterating a collection since Java 1.2